# beacon region error "incorrect argument label in call" (have identifier, expected coder)

Tags: ios, swift2, ibeacon

im new in swift so im trying to set beacon region but i get this error:
incorrect argument label in call (have 'identifier:', expected 'coder:')

below i'll post a screenshot:
[image]

heres my code:

```
let region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: NSUUID (UUIDString: "B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D")!, identifier: "Estimotes")
```

[image]

Comment: this code is compiled properly in my workspace xCode7.2, Which xCode version you used because  swift version is not stable

Comment: @rohitSidpara Xcode 7.3

Comment: Try restarting XCode.  Sometimes its Swift parsing can get out of whack.

Comment: @davidgyoung i get 5 errors now after i restarted Xcode. i'll edit the question with the new screenshot

Comment: ah i restarted again and it strangely started working. sorry guys